# How to spell and write ஃ(tamil) in English?

Tags: translation

I need a English word for the sound of one famous Tamil language letter

> **ஃ**

How is this sound written in English?

Comment: Hi @Josh61 , Google always fails to translate tamil language? thats why i raise the question here.

Comment: Why would there be an English word for a Tamil letter? Wikipedia calls it "āytam," although it appears this is just a way of writing the Tamil name using the Latin alphabet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visarga#Tamil

Comment: Hi @sumelic "āytam," cannot use, Wikipedia gives example of the Tamil letter ஃ, If I cal you by your name sumelic in English, the same pronunciation should be Tamil also.Please hear the sound of ஃ letter from this link [ஃ](https://translate.google.com/#en/ta/%E0%AE%83)

Comment: So do you want an English word that acts as a name for the letter, or a way to represent the *sound* of the Tamil letter in English? I'm confused.

Comment: English word of this sound. @sumelic

Comment: There is no English word to represent this sound (now someone will find an obscure medieval manuscript with the answer), the sound is unlike anything I have ever heard of, I clicked on the right hand side. I wouldn't know where to begin, *hag*? The -g is hard as in *gate* ( Google suggests H, which is I suppose the closest...

Comment: I found another place where Wikipedia instead says that this symbol is called "akh": that seems to be what the Google speaker is saying. I'm confused about what it's supposed to sound like; the Wikipedia article seems to say that it has no sound on its own. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script#Compound_form

Comment: It's not really about the English language though, is it? I mean I could now ask users to say what the Italian *gli* sound is in English and people would be hard pushed to come up with an accurate/precise answer. Delightful YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtlU3pMRHbU

Comment: The nearest I can suggest is 'agch' where the 'ch' is pronounced as in the Scottish word 'loch'. This can be heard in the first version here ---> http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/loch ---> Another possibility is 'agkh'

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script) says "The special letter ஃ (called akh) is the visarga. It traditionally served a purely grammatical function, but in modern times it has come to be used as a diacritic to represent foreign sounds. For example, ஃப is used for the English sound f, not found in Tamil." So there is no single sound!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Let's learn Tamil](http://fos.cmb.ac.lk/blog/lets-learn-tamil-lesson-01/)

> And a unique letter  for Tamil – **Aaytham**  ஆய்தம் = ஃ (not commonly used in spoken and written Tamil nowadays)

pronunciation [image]

In Wikipedia

> In the Tamil script, the *[visarga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visarga)* is called **āytam**, written ஃ. Apart from a modern use as a diacritic to write foreign sounds, it is archaic and employed only in idiomatic and fossilized words such as அஃது (adhu - "there"), இஃது (idhu - "here") etc.

and in Wikipedia's [Tamil script](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Tamil/Tamil_Script)

> Special letter ஃ (**pronounced** **'akh'**) is rarely used by itself - normally serves purely grammatical function as independent vowel form of the dot on consonants that suppresses the inherent 'a' sound in plain consonants.

and [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Tamil)

**[x]** guttural "ch", as in Scottish lo**ch** or German Ba**ch**

> The voiceless velar fricative is a type of consonantal sound used in some spoken languages. It was part of the consonant inventory of Old English and can still be found in some dialects of English, most notably in Scottish English *loch*.
>
> [The symbol in the International Phonetic Alphabet that represents this sound is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative) ⟨x⟩.

Finally, in [Taking Tamil to the Next Generation](https://suganthinadar.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/%E0%AE%86%E0%AE%AF%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D-ayudham/)

[image]

> **Aayudham** looks like three dots (ஃ). It does not belong with vowels or consonants, but when children are learning it always comes at the end of Tamil vowels. Ayudham has a very unique place in the Tamil language yet it’s uses are very minimal.

**Conclusion**
there are different opinions on how to spell this Tamil letter in English:
*Aaytham*,  *āytam*, *aayutham*, and *aayudham*. And there appears to be no common agreement on how to spell its pronunciation: *aq*, *akh* or *uck*. However, an IPA symbol has been assigned,  [x] , which I would recommend the OP to employ.

Comment: I am a native Tamil speaker and I could have never come up with such a brilliant and well-formulated answer! I doff my hat to you!!

Comment: @BiscuitBoy oh thank you! I blush, it's really nice to hear when an answer has proven useful.